# How to send sms from .Net application via phone connected to pc

Tags: c#, android, iphone, .net, sms

We have a legacy .Net application which can send/receive sms from the connected phone, currently it uses old Nokia 5110 phone to send/recieve sms. It uses a third party FBus dll to communicate with the phone. We want to move away from the old phone and use some of the latest phones (i.e. Android/iPhone/WindowsPhone etc.).

I googled a lot to find but every post is suggesting to use some sort of sms gateway and send an email to it to send an sms. But our requirement is, connect the phone with pc and use some sort of api to send/recieve sms via .Net. Also many posts on the net suggets creating an app for the phone, which is not what we want.

Can anybody please suggest some api with we can connect the phone with pc and we can communicate with the phone somehow.

Thanks in advance.